# Mongoid: Check if embedded object changed?

Tags: mongoid, embed

Is there a way to check if embedded objects changed? I don't find anything like `post.comments_changed?`.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :comments
end
```

Comment: try https://github.com/versative/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking

Comment: Thank you! If you add this as an answer I'm willing to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can check if embedded docs has changed or not by using  mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking
ruby gem

eg.
post.relations_changed?

check  this for more info:-  [github.com/versative/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking](https://github.com/versative/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking)

Comment: This only works for `mongoid -  < 4` as mentioned in the dependencies. Let me know how can it help for mongoid 5 and onwards.